# GHC Panic: Loading temp shared object failed

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

We're working on a fork of Parsec (with complete QuickCheck test-suite, better error messages and other improvements) and some progress has been done. Most of the time I worked with REPL from Emacs, specifying build target `tests` (that is, obviously name of the test suite). This has been working fine.

Now our thing passes the tests, everything seems to be OK, but if I start REPL with library target (or omitting it, i.e. `cabal repl` or `cabal repl lib:megaparsec`) and do something, I get GHC panic:

```
λ> parseTest (string "rere" <* eof) "reri"
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.10.1 for x86_64-unknown-linux):
    Loading temp shared object failed: /tmp/ghc9380_0/libghc9380_93.so: undefined symbol: _hpc_tickboxes_megapzuEw3SHAmfXgNLpm5a31oXO6_TextziMegaparsecziError_hpc

Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
```

Since the code compiles and works fine via `cabal repl tests`, I conclude this is not my programming fault at any rate, but may be it is a bug.

I've found this ticket: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10761, but our library doesn't use Template Haskell.

Actual question is: what should I do and how can this be fixed? I cannot even tell if it's Cabal or GHC, I have no idea how to build minimal example that could reproduce the problem.

---

I've reported it:

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10765#ticket

Comment: This looks like some weirdness related to `HPC` (haskell program coverage). Have you tried disabling HPC (running `cabal clean` and then configuring again, making sure `HPC` is not enabled?)

Comment: @bennofs, indeed, without `--enable-coverage` option this doesn't happen! How did you know that this is `HPC`-related? Also add this as an answer, this may be useful for future readers :-D Should I report bug to HPC maintainers or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read the error carefully, you'll notice that the function that is missing is related to hpc:

```
undefined symbol: _hpc_tickboxes_megapzuEw3SHAmfXgNLpm5a31oXO6_TextziMegaparsecziError_hpc
```

My guess is that the instrumentation that HPC (haskell program coverage) does is not compatible with the interactive loading of haskell code that GHCi does. Disabling HPC (`cabal clean` followed by `cabal configure`, making sure coverage is disabled when configuring) should fix the issue.

I suggest reporting a bug on the GHC bug tracker (although this could also be a cabal bug, not sure who is at fault here).

Comment: I'll try Cabal first, since it's on GitHub and it's easier for me to interact with, also I think it's rather either Cabal or HPC bug than that in GHC. Thank you, when I first saw this I thought I need to sleep sometimes because this must be a hallucination, it cannot be for real ! :-D

Comment: Well, HPC is part of GHC

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it's a separate package.